# GWT HTTP errror 503, SERVICE UNAVAILABLE

Tags: spring, hibernate, gwt

I am new to GWT, Spring and Hibernate. 
When I run sample code in GWT, Spring and Hibernate with oracle database, following error pops up.

```
HTTP ERROR: 503

Problem accessing /ECMSoftware.html. Reason:

    Service Unavailable
Powered by Jetty://
```

The html ( ECMSoftweare.html ) is created under /war/ECMSoftware.html.

Is there any hints to solve the issue ?

Comment: I am facing the same problem but i can't find a solution. can u pls help me?